# Analyzers have yellow triangles in .NET Core project

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I have a .NET Core 3.1 project and all of the entries under `Dependencies > Analyzers` in Visual Studio 2019 have yellow triangles next to them. I've verified that the files exist. I checked the various log types in the Output pane but there are no messages that seem pertinent. Building the project works fine.

[image: Yellow triangles next to Analyzers in .NET Core project]

Answer (score 3):

It appears this is a known issue, tracked here:

[Github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/5418)

Comment: Apparently this bug has now been [fixed](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/823300/analyzer-produces-yellow-icon-no-warning-messages.html).